# Are there any ways to self-inflict stress damage without also taking lethal damage?

Tags: spycraft

I am building a character that will capitalize on the Spookbusters "Prudence" feat chain, but until I get the supremacy feat, I will need a way to self inflict stress damage.

Attack gadgets specifically forbid stress as the damage type, and I can't think of another way.

I have thought about using All or Nothing on an R&R check to increase the chance of an error, but that's kind of a toss up.  The other possibility is using Manipulate/Harass Skill check gadgets on myself.

Apart from that, nothing really comes to mind.  Are there any other ways of inflicting stress on yourself that isn't effect of lethal damage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## There *are* ways to deal yourself stress damage

None will be very dignified.

- Go skydiving (pp. 108-9). Accumulate all the stress damage you need *via* failure; accumulate significantly less on a success.
- Spray yourself with a flamethrower's igniter fluid (pp. 313-4). *Pro Tip:* Do *not* do so near an open flame.
- Get blinded and stunned by a flash/bang grenade (pp. 252, 334, 338). Not only is it among the game's best weapons, but also if you set one off and *don't* throw it—*surprise!*—that's stressful.

Note that although the trick Flail from the feat Prudence Moves (*Spookbusters* 12) says...

> You may add any stress damage you’re currently suffering as lethal damage when you hit with an unarmed attack.

...the usual cap of a +4 to +6 bonus *should* apply (in the same way such a cap *should* apply to the Rhino Lift trick from the feat Club Moves (*World on Fire* 139), for example). In a game as tightly wound as *Spycraft 2.0*, the system's liable to snap, for example, if the agent makes a few carefully monitored untrained skydiving checks, doesn't die, becomes a bundle of anxiety, and nervously punches folks with his +20 or whatever bonus to damage with unarmed attacks.

Comment: Characters in the campaign I am playing in aren't limited by such trifling concepts as "should" or "makes sense".

Comment: Do you think you could provide a source on that +4 to +6 cap?

Comment: @Mystagogue I conflated that bonus limit with the rules for bonuses to skills (see the sidebar Behind the Curtain: Skill Checks on page 96 and, on the same page, Modifier Types). But the feat All-out Attack shows that to deal *a lot* of damage one should A) have exceptional ability scores *and* B) suffer significant penalties. While *some* power creep is present in *Spycraft 2.0* material, Prudence Moves' Flail trick is wholly unprecedented *and* unwarranted.